# Почему не декодируется base64 из склеенных строк?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, base64

Доброго всем! 
Есть строка, которая выдает ошибку при конвертации:

> 0JTQsNGA0LjQvCDRgdC60LjQtNC60YMg0L3QsCDQvdC+0LLQvtCz0L4=0LTQvdC40LUg0L/QvtC00LDRgNC60Lgh

При чем отдельные ее части:

> 0JTQsNGA0LjQvCDRgdC60LjQtNC60YMg0L3QsCDQvdC+0LLQvtCz0L4=

и

> 0LTQvdC40LUg0L/QvtC00LDRgNC60Lgh

Декодируются нормально, но если их соединить, то ошибка. Проверял себя через декодер Лебедева https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/advanced/

Как это можно решить?

Comment: Ну, собственно это и не является корректным base64. Символ `=` не может стоять в середине строки. Делите на отдельные части именно так, как вы сейчас поделили

Comment: Знак `=` может быть только в конце base64 строки и используется как заполнитель отсутствующих бит. но совсем без него произойдет сдвижка бит второй части. Если на его место поставить любой допустимый в середине строки символ - то вы в принципе получите строку, но на этом месте в строке будет стоять некий символ, который там не ожидается. единственный способ - полностью перекодировать вторую часть так, что бы подходила по битам. проще всего закодировать строку изначально целиком

Comment: пробелом разделите строки, и будет вам счастье.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Base64 конвертирует 3 байта в 4 символа, соответственно возникает проблема выравнивания длины байтов (набор байтов должен быть кратен 3), для чего и применяется символ (1 или 2) `=`, который как и написали в комментариях не может стоять в середине, а всегда в конце

Ваша исходная строка *Дарим скидку на новогодние подарки!* должна конвертироваться в строку:

> 0JTQsNGA0LjQvCDRgdC60LjQtNC60YMg0L3QsCDQvdC+0LLQvtCz0L7QtNC90LjQtSDQv9C+0LTQsNGA0LrQuCE=

которая, как нетрудно заметить слегка отличается от ваших строчек:

> 0JTQsNGA0LjQvCDRgdC60LjQtNC60YMg0L3QsCDQvdC+0LLQvtCz0L4=
>
> 0LTQvdC40LUg0L/QvtC00LDRgNC60Lgh

Короче говоря, нельзя просто так и взять конкатенировать base64 строки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, точно!